# Não consegui achar o error

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

> Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in
>   /storage/ssd4/127/9971127/public_html/excluir.php:6 Stack trace: #0
>   {main} thrown in /storage/ssd4/127/9971127/public_html/excluir.php on
>   line 6

```
<?php

include_once('CONEXAO.php');

$CONEXAO = new CONEXAO();
$ID = $_POST('ID');

$smtp = $CONEXAO->conn->prepare('DELETE FROM USUARIO WHERE ID = :ID');
$smtp->execute(array('ID' => $ID));

if($smtp){
    echo 'excluido com sucesso';
}else{
    echo 'item invalido';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST` é uma variável (array) global e estas a chamar em forma de função..
tenta assim:

```
$ID = $_POST['ID'];
```

Comment: obrigado nem percebi kkkkkk valeu